# YOLOv3 Netmodel?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I see that YOLOv2 is on the [Wolfram net repo](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/YOLO-V2-Trained-on-MS-COCO-Data_1), but has anyone ported the new [YOLO version 3](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/YOLOv3.pdf) architecture into Mathematica?

Comment: Not yet. Converting from Darknet it's a pain and I don't have much time. I may post it here when we have some working network.

Comment: Looks like it is here now. https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/YOLO-V3-Trained-on-Open-Images-Data/